# Does the .NET 3.0 SP1 installer also install .NET 2.0 and 3.0?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, .net-3.0

.NET 3.0 "wraps" .NET 2.0 so if I'm starting out with a clean Windows Server 2003 environment, will the .NET 3.0 SP1 installer also install .NET 2.0 and 3.0? What about .NET 2.0 SP1? Assume I don't want to install .NET 3.5 SP1 just yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just install .NET 3.5 SP1, and you'll get .NET 2.0 SP1 and SP2, as well as .NET 3.0 SP1 and SP2.

Comment: slight correction. .net 3.5 sp1 includes sp2 for .net 3.0 also

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected that. It was 3.5 RTM that had 3.0 SP1?

Answer (score 1):

The .NET 3.0 installer does install .NET 2.0 - the difference is in libraries only; the runtime under .NET 3.0 is still v2, though with some minor-ish patches.

The runtime under .NET 3.5 is still v2 as well - all the stuff that's new in .NET 3.5 is a mix of compiler magic and some funky libraries.

FWIW, The next version of the .NET *runtime* is going to be 4.0 - there won't be a v3.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=EC2CA85D-B255-4425-9E65-1E88A0BDB72A&displaylang=en) , I don't think so.  However, it's supposed to be backwards-compatible, more or less.